# CS fundamental knowledge

Tags: computer-science

I have been programming a lot over the years. I use C/C++ with make/open source code in Linux. I use Python to prototype the algorithms. I use C#/Visual C++ MFC to create toy programs on Windows. And these codes are kept under version control system. But after reviewing interview questions for software engineering, I realize that I still don't have the fundamental knowledge of CS. Most of my programming is "blind" without any careful design. So my question is what are the basic CS knowledge that a SE must know?

1) Data structures and algorithms

2) Discrete Math

Anything else should I study?

Comment: Wrong place to ask, since unrelated to source code. Try on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ and read http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/ ; also learn to use Linux, and study free software source code of your choice.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: This question will probably be closed. My recommendations, in no particular order: computer architecture (CPU, memory, cache, bus, interconnect, etc.); operating systems (how they work, not how to use them); networking (how protocols work, not how to write chat apps); compilers and/or formal language theory (Chomsky hierarchy, regular expressions and languages, context-free languages, undecidability, etc.); discrete math (propositional and predicate logic, basic set theory and mathematical notation, graphs and trees, etc.); and the stuff you already mention.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good idea to be familiar (at least) with the same topics that a major university would require for a bachelors degree.  For example: http://www.engin.umd.umich.edu/SRA/pdf/curriculum/Curr_SWE_Fall_2008.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The transition from a "coder" to a "software engineer" is a lifelong process. The fact that you recognize your weaknesses in the area indicates that you've already made some steps in the right direction. Congratulations!

After a solid knowledge of data structures and basic algorithms, I would suggest "Design Patterns" as your #2. The classic text for this is "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software"

A third area of study could be "Software Engineering Process". These are the techniques and workflows used when teams of people are creating software. Companies look favorably on knowledge of these processes, and the ability to work with others in a coordinated fashion.